# @NgModules confusion about dynamic bootstrapping

Tags: angularjs, angular

I've got rc7 installed and my module and component works.

However I want to use it on a webpage and make my modules and components only bootstrap if the current page has the selector to be bootstrapped with.

I am using one module and declare my components. But I can't bootstrap at least one. As far as I understand I should be fine using one module for the whole website and dynamically bootstrapping components if the page has the element that needs the components bootstrapped.

Currently I get errors if I don't boostrap anything in my module and I also get errors if I bootstrap a component and the selector doesn't exist on the page. Is there a way of avoiding these errors? Or am I using wrong stuff? Should I be using something else for this purpose instead of modules and components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check yourself (`document.querySelector(...)`) if the page contains a matching selector before you call `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`